# update failure galaxy core 2

Tags: rooting, boot-loop

well first of all, my phone is rooted. the phone notified me about an update I accidentally pressed update and now its in an endless loop where it will update then fail and update again. please help, I'm getting desperate

Comment: Take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device). You will need to flash a "stock" version of the ROM. You might even find one that is stock, but also contains root if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

The update should have stopped as soon as it found that the phone was rooted and not updated it. (Boot-looping is one of the mildest problems if you update a rooted ROM with a non-rooted update that hasn't been modified to update the modifications done to the rooted one.)

1. Go to SamMobile Firmwares and find the stock ROM for your device (use the model number, not "core 2")
2. Download Odin and install it on your computer
3. Download the ROM to the computer (you'll have to create a free account on SamMobile to download anything) and flash the stock ROM to your phone.
4. Then update it. (If the latest stock ROM is a couple of versions old, you'll have to update more than once to get to the latest version, and you can only update once every 24 hours.)

Flashing the ROM is simple:

1. After installing Odin, unzip the downloaded ROM.
2. There will be files starting with AP, BL, etc. Load the files into the appropriate slots in Odin (the AP file goes into the AP slot, etc.)
3. Plug the phone in and one of the boxes at the top of Odin should show COM and a number after a short time. (You have to have the SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones installed in the computer.)
4. Once you see that (the number doesn't matter) and you have the files, run Odin and wait for the phone to restart.

If the ROM isn't the latest version, you'll start getting "there's an update ..." notices. If you want the update, press OK (make sure the battery is up to at least 75% and keeping the charger plugged in isn't a bad idea either) and the phone will download the update and install it.

If that's not the latest update (some are cumulative - they include all changes since the version you have, others aren't and you have to update a step at a time), you'll get another notice the next day, and so on, until you're current.

Then root the updated ROM.

The next time you want an update, you're going to have to do the same thing - revert to stock, update, root. (If being rooted is important to you, make sure there's a current rooting method for your phone for the updated ROM version before you update.)

By the way, the 0.95MB update is probably the "get the phone ready for the next update" update. They do that every so often - some things have to be changed before an update. Or it may be a minor bug fix.

In any case, if the phone is rooted, something wasn't where the update expected it to be, so the updated software is crashing. It's possible to successfully update a rooted phone, it's also possible to hard brick it (it acts the same whether there's a battery in it or not - like a brick). What happens depends on what happened while the phone was rooted and what the update does. Since there are so many variables that winning every throw of the dice in Vegas is a sure thing by comparison, the updating process checks 2 things - that the ROM is the stock one and that the phone has never been rooted. If either test fails, it's supposed to stop with an error message (to the effect that the update failed, even though that's not really true). Evidently, for some reason, yours failed to stop.